# If $p$ is a prime, then $(p-1)! \equiv -1 (mod p)$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, factorial

> If $p$ is a prime, then $(p-1)! \equiv -1 (mod p)$. Hint: $(p-1)!$ is the product of elements in $Z_p$. Match each element to its inverse.

I can understand by testing some primes that for any prime $(p-1)!+1$ is a multiple of that prime, but I'm not sure how to prove it in general or how inverses play into it.

Comment: What about the hint given to you? "How do inverses play into it" well, inverses cancel each other out, so you need to locate the inverses in the product $(p-1)!$, and see what cancels out, and what does not. Some elements in that product have an inverse in that product. Some, do not.

Comment: Look up Wilson's Theorem either via google or in any intro number theory book. [that's the displayed statement]

Comment: There are only even number amount of elements in the group, and $a=a^{-1}$ iff $a=\pm1$.

Comment: It is Wilson's Theorem and the converse is also true

Comment: I'm assuming this is a group theory course, and OP might not want a number theory proof.

Comment: i made it too complicated for myself. thank you everyone